# Unable to record inbound and outbound call voice and app gets killed in background when app is closed

Tags: android, service, android-10.0

below is the code which I'm trying

MainActivity.java

> package com.aravindchowdary.callrecorder.CallRecording;
>
> import android.Manifest; import android.app.admin.DevicePolicyManager;
>   import android.content.ComponentName; import android.content.Context;
>   import android.content.Intent; import
>   android.content.SharedPreferences; import
>   android.content.pm.PackageManager; import android.net.Uri; import
>   android.preference.PreferenceManager;
>
> import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat; import
>   androidx.core.content.ContextCompat; import
>   androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
>
> import android.os.Bundle; import android.util.Log; import
>   android.view.View; import android.widget.Button; import
>   android.widget.EditText; import android.widget.Toast;
>
> import com.aravindchowdary.callrecorder.Preferences; import
>   com.aravindchowdary.callrecorder.R;
>
> import java.util.ArrayList; import java.util.List;
>
> public class RecordActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
>       private boolean checkResume = false;
>       private String phone;
>       private EditText etCall;
>       private Preferences preferences;
>       public static final String TAG = "PhoneStateReceiver";
>       private static final int REQUEST_CODE = 0;
>       private DevicePolicyManager mDPM;
>       private ComponentName mAdminName;
>
> ```
> @Override
> protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
>     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
>     setContentView(R.layout.activity_record);
>     preferences = Preferences.getSharedPrefInstance(this);
>
>     SharedPreferences pref = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>     pref.edit().putInt("numOfCalls", 0).apply();
>
>     Button btnCall = findViewById(R.id.btnCall);
>     etCall = findViewById(R.id.etCall);
>
>
>     btnCall.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
>         @Override
>         public void onClick(View v) {
>             if (validateCall()) {
>                 preferences.saveCall(true);
>                 Log.d(TAG, "PrefcallSave: " + preferences.getcall());
>                 Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_DIAL, Uri.fromParts("tel", phone, null));
>                 startActivity(intent);
>             }
>         }
>     });
>
> }
>
> private boolean validateCall() {
>     phone = etCall.getText().toString().trim();
>     if (phone.isEmpty()) {
>         etCall.setError("Phone number can't be empty");
>     } else {
>         return true;
>     }
>     return false;
> }
>
> @Override
> protected void onResume() {
>     super.onResume();
>     Log.e("Check", "onResume: ");
>     if (checkPermission()) {
>         if (checkResume == false) {
>         }
>     }
> }
>
> protected void onPause() {
>     super.onPause();
>     SharedPreferences pref3 = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this);
>     if (pref3.getBoolean("pauseStateVLC", false)) {
>         checkResume = true;
>         pref3.edit().putBoolean("pauseStateVLC", false).apply();
>     } else
>         checkResume = false;
> }
>
> private boolean checkPermission() {
>     int i = 0;
>     String[] perm = {Manifest.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE, Manifest.permission.RECORD_AUDIO,
> ```
>
> Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
>   Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE,
>   Manifest.permission.READ_CONTACTS};
>           List reqPerm = new ArrayList<>();
>
> ```
>     for (String permis : perm) {
>         int resultPhone = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(RecordActivity.this, permis);
>         if (resultPhone == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
>             i++;
>         else {
>             reqPerm.add(permis);
>         }
>     }
>
>     if (i == 5)
>         return true;
>     else
>         return requestPermission(reqPerm);
> }
>
>
> private boolean requestPermission(List<String> perm) {
>
>     String[] listReq = new String[perm.size()];
>     listReq = perm.toArray(listReq);
>     for (String permissions : listReq) {
>         if (ActivityCompat.shouldShowRequestPermissionRationale(RecordActivity.this,
> ```
>
> permissions)) {
>                   Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Phone Permissions needed for " + permissions, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>               }
>           }
>
> ```
>     ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(RecordActivity.this, listReq, 1);
>
>
>     return false;
> }
>
>
> public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String permissions[], int[] grantResults) {
>     switch (requestCode) {
>         case 1:
>             if (grantResults.length > 0 && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Permission Granted to access Phone calls", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>             else
>                 Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "You can't access Phone calls", Toast.LENGTH_LONG);
>             break;
>     }
>
> } }
> ```

please help me to sort this issue thanks in advance